# I cant upgrade the lxml version,

Tags: python, lxml, setup.py, libxml2

i get the message "Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?"
Also

```
PS C:\Users\herna> pip install lxml --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\users\herna\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (4.9.0)
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.9.1.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
```

```
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
      *********************************************************************************
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Attempting uninstall: lxml
    Found existing installation: lxml 4.9.0
    Uninstalling lxml-4.9.0:
      Successfully uninstalled lxml-4.9.0
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

I have tried forcing reinstall, installing lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl